# MMS can not send to Android phone: gets iMessage error

Tags: messages

This has happened twice, with two different Android recipients.

Both have been Android phones since inception - read: never had iMessage, so Apple shouldn't be confused about iMessage.

Anyway, we've had recent failures sending pics to Android phones we've sent pics before.  We get:

```
Cannot Send Message
iMessage needs to be enabled to send this message
```

iMessage *is* enabled.

So, I tried a phone bounce, disabling/re-enabling iMessages, disabling/re-enabling MMS.  Disabling/re-enabling WiFi (TMobile, allows WiFi as an SMS/MMS transport). No good.  A simple text message worked tho.  just no pics

Tips?

EDIT: versions would be nice.  iOS 8.3.  iPhone 6.

UPDATE: I was able to send by sending to a new MMS group; the intended recipient and an iMessage account.

Comment: I have the same issue, but cannot recieve MMS and also group messages fail

Comment: @JonathanLeaders I got it to work, not sure how :(. Maybe have them send you a message. It may reset some "has iMessage" flag locally on your phone.